# Data storage and access within Vue component or Vuex module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to determine the best way to lay out this structure and data. I've gone round and round with different ideas and still haven't 100% settled on anything.

I have a virtual scrolling data table component that I made. It also allows the user to select rows to perform certain actions on them. The actions aren't specific to the table, they could be anything and so that functionality is not within the table itself. I wanted the selection state of the rows to exist within the table component itself. Having it in the store module would mean that every store module that would make use of this component would have to implement those functions again. The actions that are performed on the data though, being external to the table, means I need to know what items are selected in the table. This leads me to think that the selection does in fact need to be in the store module and not JUST in the table.

Am I thinking about this correctly? It should be in the store module? What's the most common way of doing something like this so that I don't have to replicate that code for each module? Should I just make a generic node module or something that I import into the store module that mutates them? Or make a node module that I can import and spread into the mutations and actions that already do all of that?

Thanks

Comment: Use events.  Your table can keep an internal list of its selected row indexes (or ids, etc).  Whenever you select or deselect an item, emit a custom `change` event with the list.  Or, you could emit `selected` and `deselected` events having just the individual index/id if you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

you can bind click event on table-row or some other elements, every time you trigger it, such as clicking on the row, you store some data, id, index etc, to vuex or component's data, release it when you deselect this row. When you want to operate it, you can filter id to find it, then you can make any operation you want.